# Execute multiple `docker-compose run` that are encapsulated from of each other

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose` file that looks like the following:

```
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6.12
    container_name: mongo-${BUILD_ID}
  app:
    image: repo/my-image:latest
    container_name: app-${BUILD_ID}
    working_dir: /src
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```

I'm running this in a CI/CD pipeline to execute tests in parallel via a `docker-compose run app run-test-1.sh` but have noticed only one instance of a `mongo` container is created. This seems to result in the tests interfering with each other. Is it possible to `docker-compose run` such that it will create both the `app` service and the `mongo` service together and encapsulated from other `docker-compose run` containers so that they each have their own `mongo` instance?

I have tried the following to no avail:

- Adding a `container_name: mongo-${BUILD_ID}` property in the `docker-compose.yml`
- Adding the `--name` flag when executing the command. i.e. `docker-compose run --name id1 app run-test-1.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Managed to figure this out. `docker-compose` has a flag `--project-name` which it will use instead of the default value (folder name).

Thus my `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6.12
  app:
    image: repo/my-image:latest
    working_dir: /src
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```

and I can execute the following commands and each will be namespaced within their respective project names:

- `docker-compose --project-name project1 run app ./run-test1.sh`.
- `docker-compose --project-name project2 run app ./run-test2.sh`.
- `docker-compose --project-name project3 run app ./run-test3.sh`.

I